# AWS Systems Manager Run Command execution timeout when I use nohup &

Tags: amazon-web-services, nohup, aws-ssm, runcommand

**AWS Systems Manager Run Command**

when I use command `nohup &` it returns execution timeout

Does AWS Systems Manager Run command not supports background process?

How to fix this problem?